# Is it possible to add a Facebook Messenger Bot Tester from a phone number user?

Tags: facebook, botframework, bots, facebook-messenger, messenger

There are users on facebook messenger without a facebook account, I want to add one of these users as a tester of the bot.
I want to add it here [image: Here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible. The user has to have an FB developer account to accept an app role.

Comment: Thank you! would you please give me the source of this info?

Comment: I don't think this is actually documented anywhere, but you need an FB account to create a developer account, and creating a Messenger account using phone number does not create a proper FB account.